# Can I use the same ArrayAdapter in two different listViews? How?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I need to use the same ArrayAdapter in two activities. In MainActivity i  need to show only Items with isConsumido() = true and in another activity i need to show all Items.

My MainActivity adapter:

```
        final ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> arrayAdapterOrdenado = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturaisOrdenados());
```

Now, im using two adapters, but when i check isConsumido() in one item of adapter from TelaCadastrados, the same item in MainActivity need to turn invisible, and when i remove item on TelaCadastrados, the same item need to be removed on MainActivity.

My TelaCadastrados adapter:

```
        final ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais());
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that!

Comment: Yes, if they use similar or the same  layout file and data

Answer (score 1):

You should use 2 adapters, but they can have a common data set, so when you change something it affects both adapters at the same time. But remember to call notifyDataSetChanged() in both adapters.

Comment: How can I make  invisible certain item of my ArrayAdapter,when  the same shall belong to two screens, but i just want to make invisible in one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't share the adapter, share the underlying data set. You have list of the data objects, and the adapter wraps that list. Share the list, not the adapter.

Your `isConsumido() = true` logic is a property of the adapter (constructor argument). You'll have to create a custom adapter to add that behavior.

You can store the list of `ItemCultural` in your application class, so in each activity, you do something like,

```
List<ItemCultural> data = ((MyApplication)getApplication).getData();
final ArrayAdapter<ItemCultural> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, data);
```

Someone will probably tell you to store the data in a static. Don't do that.

Comment: How can I make  invisible certain item of my ArrayAdapter,when  the same shall belong to two screens, but i just want to make invisible in one.

Comment: Code it :) You need to have a custom adapter. That custom adapter conditional renders your `ItemCultural` object. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view to get started with a custom adapter. `ArrayAdapter` is not sophisticated enough to give you what you want.